# Matlab - eigenvalue doesn't zero the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, condition-number

I created a symmetric $21 \times 21$ matrix $A$ with condition number $7.5044$. I wrote the following code:

```
syms x;
AS = sym(A);
polyA = charpoly(AS,x);
solve(polyA);
```

and this is the result

```
  93.988842796147505104718718233034
  63.318989852350135397493503048259
  38.392863684000190231816927188875
  57.023973670819117411135094232301
  20.964197497113106525263127789941
  52.100859003607712279511955297751
  14.457776205660758291480361189262
  72.543368263184623095490492872815
 -19.500133944896490949432003697463
  65.733078713316290701540791543043
  71.723898977718034735792925663278
  57.262150118578505531059649955477
  27.620774843148443240592651344762
  49.356126883789838887152595264487
  51.847578071455088288616446818711
  70.832873937409296415793129090208
  12.524474726415933018910355256388
  37.721878707889458815773572522044
 -39.123034260347914003761194641743
  82.618237465274092122200710770248
  12.591224787366274858850190258322
```

I expect the following code to be close to zero

```
double(subs(polyA,37.721878707889458815773572522044))
```

But the answer of the matlab is `-2.2191e+11`, other eigenvalues generate other big numbers as well. Why the eigenvalues don't zero the `polyA` while the condition number is just $\approx 7$?

Comment: If you pick a larger symmetric matrices you can observe complex eigenvalues found by MATLAB. :-)

Comment: @dEmigOd really?! Well it is the limits of the computations. May be we need to switch to quantum computing in the future ;)

Comment: How did you create matrix `A`? It would be useful to know, so one can use, say, SymPy instead.